# How should I deal with an Live wallpaper so it supports multiple aspect ratios?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, android-animation, live-wallpaper

I have a live wallpaper all set up (for simplicity's sake, assume it consists of two rotating bitmaps positioned side by side, each rotating at different speeds; also note that the bitmaps' edges (not the invisible box around the image, but rather the actual pixels of the drawing) are touching.)

I described the translate for each as a percentage of the canvas size (a value between 0 and 1 multiplied by c.getHeight(), and c.getWidth() (where c is a canvas).)

Anyways, everything works fine as long the aspect ratio is maintained. So xxhdpi and xhdpi @ 1080x1920 and 720x1280 is all good, but then when i run it on a nexus s @ 480x800, the two bitmaps are no longer positioned properly.

I do not want to distort my images (they are circles and must remain circles), so I was thinking the best way would be the limit the size of the canvas and center it.

So for the nexus s @ 480x800, i would actually want to only draw in a 450x800 area which i would center on my screen.

In fact, I would always want to have my 2 bitmaps in an area respecting the height = width * 0.5625.

How should I go about doing this?

NB: I based my live wallpaper around the cube sample.

Please let me know if I left any important details out,

Thank you!

Werner

Answer (score 0):

inside your Engine, implement following to capture the screen's height and width

```
int screenHeight, screenWidth;
@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
    screenHeight = height; screenWidth = width;
}
```

and wherever you decode your bitmap, do it like this:-

```
//get bitmap
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.bitmap);

//scale bitmap
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, screenWidth, screenWidth * 0.5625, true);
```

This will fill your entire screen with a circle of correct aspect ratio (width * 0.5625).

And then make it centred by:-

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();
Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

int x = ( screenHeight - screenWidth*0.5625 ) / 2;

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, x, paint);
```